# How do you zoom in a scrollviewer in UWP but keep the width and height of the scrollviewer stretched to fit in the parent panel or grid column?

Tags: xaml, uwp, resize, zooming, scrollviewer

See the images below. One is at 78% zoom but the whole content is zoomed out but not stretching to its parent control despite having Horizontal and Vertical Alignment set to "stretch".

ScrollViewer is in a GridColumn and GridRow and the Grid is being loaded into a Frame which is a part of the NavigationView on the mainpage.

[image]

[image]

Desired effect is for the content to get smaller but fit to the width and height to show more columns in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> See the images below. One is at 78% zoom but the whole content is zoomed out but not stretching to its parent control despite having Horizontal and Vertical Alignment set to "stretch".

This behavior of `ScrollViewer` is by-deign, derive from the screenshot the `DataGrid` is a whole place.  When we zoom in or out, The `DataGrid` will zoom overall. For the requirement, you could edit the DataGrid's `MaxColumnWidth` property when zoom.

Comment: What do you mean edit the DataGrid's MaxColumnWidth?
I still want the zoom out and in effect